# AutocomplteTextView android map

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

In my android application I want add **AutocomplteTextView** I follow this link: https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/places/autocomplete-android

I think it provides a best way to add a **AutocomplteTextView** in my map.
I am new to android & java so I have **no idea to place this codes ..**
 Now I have a **OpenMap** class  **extends MapActivity { }**

Please help me ..